Get AWS Cognito user info from JWT bearer token
I have an AWS cognito user pool set up with an app client.
When I analyze authenticated requests coming from my front end I can extract bearer tokens and decode them using jwt.io. For example I decoded the following one:
{
  'sub': 'pu5****o03s', 
  'client_id': 'pu5****o03s'
  'token_use': 'access', 
  'scope': 'app/access', 
  'auth_time': 1717751982, 
  'iss': 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XXXXXXX', 
  'exp': 1717755582, 
  'iat': 1717751982, 
  'version': 2, 
  'jti': 'fd42356e-0d9a-54b4-b461-9177f89c5945'
}

What puzzles me is that the sub claim is the same as the client_id. When looking at my app integration config in AWS cognito console, I can confirm it is indeed the app client id as you can see below:

I am not sure how this is possible, perhaps a config issue or something else within the token issuance process. All I am trying to do is to obtain some identifying information in regards to who the token was created for. An email address or cognito user ID would work.
